# iOS - How can I hide text inputs without leaving gaps?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am creating a form in my iOS app in which certain text fields need to be hidden depending on the number that was entered in the previous field. For example if 1 is entered there will be one field, if 4 is entered there will be four fields etc. all the way up to 25. I understand how to hide the buttons depending on number...the problem is when I hide the buttons they still leave the white space because all the fields are set up to position at x and y height. I have tried to put the inputs into a table view because I thought it would allow me to hide each table view cell containing the input and then move the rest up. But XCode gives me an error saying I can't connect IBOutlet to repeating content. Positioning the x and y height in the code won't work either because I need to do this a few times and there would be too many variables.

I have looked for a solution everywhere and haven't been able to find a solution. Does any one know how to hide text fields and make everything else below move up?

Answer (score 0):

You could use autolayout by anchor each textfield to the one above.

Or you could give a tag to each textfield and then iterate with a cycle for till the index of your previous view to setHidden:false to the textfields

Comment: Thank you autolayout by anchor seems like it could work...but how can I get the text view to anchor to the other? I tried to ctrl drag & also right click drag like it says in the tutorials but nothing is happening. It is only giving me the option for Referencing Outlets, I tried on both the view itself and the constraint.

Comment: you have to select the textview, then at the bottom right of the storyboard/xib window, tap on the button in the middle. then a little window will popup and at the top of it you can anchor the view to the ones that you want to